# Parameter Tuning for ML model with column transformer and pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, one-hot-encoding, gridsearchcv

My code works perfectly until the fitting of the final model. But I have no idea how to do GridSearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV for the pipeline. Kindly help me.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline


df = pd.read_csv('data/vehicle_dataset_v4A.csv')

X = df.drop('price', axis=1)
y = df['price']

numerical_ix = X.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64']).columns
categorical_ix = X.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'bool']).columns

col_transform = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(), categorical_ix), 
    (StandardScaler(), numerical_ix),
    remainder='passthrough'
)

model = RandomForestRegressor()

pipe = make_pipeline(col_transform,model)

pipe.fit(X, y)
```

I tried the following code. The code runs without any error but when I try to make prediction with Gridsearchcv, it throws different errors at different times. Hope there should be a solution for this. Otherwise, If I can know what are the best parameters after gridsearch, I can directly apply those parameters to the model.

```
lr = {
    'base_score':[0.4,0.45,0.5,0.55,0.6],
    'max_depth':[1,2,3,4,6,8,10],
    'subsample':[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1],
    'n_estimators': [50,100,200,250,300],
    'learning_rate':  [0.05,0.1,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.9,1],
    'min_child_weight': [0.1,0.5,1,1.5,2,3],
    'gamma': [0,0.1,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3]
    }

clf = make_pipeline(OneHotEncoder(),
                    StandardScaler(with_mean=False),
                    GridSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(),
                                 param_grid=lr,
                                 scoring='r2',cv=3,verbose=2))
```

Comment: Is this `best_estimator_` attribute what you are looking for? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV

Comment: the attributes are not working as Gridsearch is constructed with pipeline. That's where I need the help. I want to know how to know the best parameters after searching with gridsearch. Or if the way the gridsearch is done is wrong, I want to know if im doing something wrong here and get the idea how it should be done. kindly help

Answer (score -1):

Three thoughts on your application:

1. Do not use `OneHotEncoder` for `RandomForestRegressor`, you don't need it.
2. Do not use `make_pipeline`, this is overkill for your problem.
3. Firstly apply `StandardScaler` on the data, and then run `GridSearchCV`.

Please test this and give us feedback on it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The accuracy and r2 score drops drastically. Previously r2 score was 86% and after this it was dropped to 63%. 

However, instead of RandomForestRegressor if we use something else like XGBoost, we still have to go through the OneHotEncoder and StandardScaler. can you please suggest another way to solve this issue?.

Comment: What is your result, if you don't use `StandardScaler` and apply `RandomForestRegressor` out of the box without a grid search?

Comment: Without using the standard scaler, I was able to get 76% of r2 score which is less than using both standard scaler and OneHotEncoder which was 86%.